# Several formulas to solve the same problem: how to make Mathematica to run them all at the same time and chose the best?

Tags: parallelization

Suppose you have two functions that do basically the same but with different methods. For instance, integration by `Integrate` and integration by Rubi package, `Int`.

On a given argument evaluation of one or both functions may take very long time, sometimes one of them may enter an infinite loop.

You want to make a function that would combine the pros of the both methods, returning result from the one which took less time and terminate the other one. Or, maybe, initially wait a bit for the both and compare results. How this can be done?

Besides integration, I have the following example, regularization with 3 different methods:

```
Limit[s Sum[f[s x], {x, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"] //
   FullSimplify, s -> 0]
```

or

```
LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s] /. s -> 0 // Re // FullSimplify
```

or

```
I/2 FourierTransform[f[I t] Sign[t], t, s, 
    FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] /. s -> 0 // FullSimplify
```

Comment: `ParallelTry` could likely help, at least with returning the first to finish...you might need to structure things so that each deliberately goes into an infinite loop if it returns unevaluated, though.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, you could run each algorithm using time out. Collect the information you need about the results and return back to the user a report.

For example, for integrate, this compares Rubi with Mathematica. One would be interested in how much time each took, the leaf size of the result and the actual result. You could add more stats as needed.

Here is a simple function `compare` that takes the integrand and the integration variable. Here is screen shot showing 3 examples. Code all below

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows that in first example, Rubi failed to integrate. Second one Mathematica timedout (but with more time, it will probably do it) and third example both passed.

```
compare[intgrand_,var_Symbol]:=Module[{rubiResult,mmaResult,tbl,timeOut=60},
  tbl={0,0,0};
  tbl[[1]]={"Method","result","Pass/Fail","Leaf size","time used"};
  rubiResult= AbsoluteTiming[ TimeConstrained[Int[intgrand,var],timeOut]];
  If[rubiResult[[2]]===$Aborted,
       tbl[[2]]={"Rubi",rubiResult[[2]],"Failed","N/A",rubiResult[[1]]};
  ,
       If[Not[FreeQ[rubiResult[[2]],Int]], 
           tbl[[2]]={"Rubi",rubiResult[[2]],"Failed","N/A",rubiResult[[1]]}
       ,
            tbl[[2]]={"Rubi",rubiResult[[2]],"Passed",LeafCount[rubiResult[[2]]],rubiResult[[1]]}
       ]
   ];
   mmaResult= AbsoluteTiming[ TimeConstrained[Integrate[intgrand,var],timeOut]];
   If[mmaResult[[2]]===$Aborted,
       tbl[[3]]={"Mathematica",mmaResult[[2]],"Failed","N/A",mmaResult[[1]]};
   ,
       If[Not[FreeQ[mmaResult[[2]],Integrate]], 
            tbl[[3]]={"Mathematica",mmaResult[[2]],"Failed","N/A",mmaResult[[1]]}
       ,
            tbl[[3]]={"Mathematica",mmaResult[[2]],"Passed",LeafCount[mmaResult[[2]]],mmaResult[[1]]}
       ]
   ];
    
   Grid[tbl,Frame->All]

]
```

Call as

```
compare[(x^2 + 2*x*Log[x] + 
    Log[x]^2 + (1 + x)*Sqrt[x + Log[x]])/(x^3 + 2*x^2*Log[x] + 
    x*Log[x]^2), x]

compare[x/Sqrt[-71 - 96*x + 10*x^2 + x^4], x]

compare[(6 - 3*x^2 + x^4)/(4 + 5*x^2 - 5*x^4 + x^6), x]
```

To run more problems automatically, just make a loop around the above call and collect the overall result in a report.

As for choosing the "best", you decide what criteria you want. For example, for integrate, may be you need to grade the anti-derivative first against an optimal result and give A,B,C,F grade. But this depends on the problem. For integrate, it is possible to grade if you know what the optimal anti-derivative is. Leafsize and time used will also be factor in grading.

Comment: Regarding regularization, the computations can take tens of minutes, which is too much already. And the speed of the methods differs a lot. Doing 3 times this for 3 functions will be simply unbearable. That's why my desire is to *speed up* computation using the fastest method, not to slow it down by using the methods consequently.

Comment: @Anixx Lets talk about just integration for now. I thought you meant to find the algorithm which gives "best" result. Not just which finishes first. If all you want to know is the fastest one, then this is easy as suggested in comments with parallel  try (I have not used it myself). But this would be the wrong approach. In integrations, time used is just one factor out of many to use to select the best algorithm. If time was the only criteria, then Maple for example will beat Mathematica easily in integration tests as it is much faster. But then you'll be overlooking other important metrics.

Comment: .. that is why I think it is much better to set a timeout, and collect the statistics about each problem result obtained, than have separate grading stage, which goes over the stats collected and it decides which algorithm is "best". If an algorithm takes one second more, then produces much better result  than the other, why reject this? In your time only criteria, you will be doing this.  How this is all is done, depends ofcourse about the type of problem.  I am now just talking about integration. For the types of problems you mentioned, similar by different stats are needed.

Comment: I gave integration only as an example. I have several examples of where there are several methods that take different times and may or may not fail. One method may take 10 mins while the other several seconds on one input while on the other the "fast" method goes to a loop and does not stop after 10 hours.

Comment: @Anixx That is why you need to set a timeout. Common timeout for all. Same thing happens with integration. Without time out, an algorithm can take hrs on one problem.

Comment: Yes, but if I perform the methods consequentially, this will increase the time by up to 3 times on average.

Comment: That is right. But then you will miss a good algorithm because the other finished by one second earlier, but produced much worst output.  So it is really up to you what you are looking for. If speed is all what you care about, then this method I showed will not work for you. But you could run these in parallel also but each with timeout. I have not used parallel try, so I can't help with that. I hope someone else knows how to do it that way.  (Title of your question says "choose the best"). May be you should change that to "Choose the fastest" in this case.

Comment: Well, in my setting the best means fastest and correct, some methods may fail or return wrong output, like infinities in the case of regularization (which is intended to get rid of infinities). Thus, the primary considerations are speed and correctness.

Comment: No, it will not do the second integral, because 10 seconds is the timeout of IntegrateAlgebraic. It will give only nonelementary result, anyway how is that possible? Here it only takes 3 seconds, 9 seconds in the cloud.